# nextjs react-three/drei useFBX cannot read fbx file

Tags: next.js, blender, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei, mixamo

I am following [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGMKIyALcK0&list=PLpepLKamtPjguLKYT7c66998iTaWvqSRe) to animate my 3d .glb avatar  created using [readyplayer](https://readyplayer.me/) service. I have managed to load the avatar model in my nextJs app.

In order to get the animation file from [mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/), I imported the .glb into .fbx format using blender, then uploaded the .fbx file to [mixamo](https://www.mixamo.com/). I chose "typing" animation, then saved the file "Typing.fbx" into the "/public/animations/Typing.fbx" of my nextJs app folder.

I then loaded the file with

```
const {animation:typingAnimation} = useFBX("/animations/Typing.fbx")
```

However, as I tried to

```
console.log(typingAnimation)
```

the result is undefined.

Please help me to load this typing animation file, so I can animate my 3d .glb avatar in nextJs.

This is the [original .glb avatar](https://models.readyplayer.me/65c32117cb01177237fdc454.glb), and if you want to replicate the issue, this is [the github repo](https://github.com/Petrando/three-d).
The avatar file is located in

```
/public/images/3d/avatar.glb
```

**Edit** : the complete code is as follows :

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useFBX, useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

export function Avatar(props) {
  //the code below is where I load my 3d avatar model, it works correctly
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/images/3d/avatar.glb");

  //the code below is where I call the animation file
  const {animation:typingAnimation} = useFBX("/animations/TypingAgain.fbx")
  

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(typingAnimation)//this is where it failed, the result is undefined
  }, [typingAnimation])

  //the return statement below can display my 3d avatar model
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <primitive object={nodes.Hips} />
      <skinnedMesh
        name="EyeLeft"
        geometry={nodes.EyeLeft.geometry}
        material={materials.Wolf3D_Eye}
        skeleton={nodes.EyeLeft.skeleton}
        morphTargetDictionary={nodes.EyeLeft.morphTargetDictionary}
        morphTargetInfluences={nodes.EyeLeft.morphTargetInfluences}
      />
      <skinnedMesh
        name="EyeRight"
        geometry={nodes.EyeRight.geometry}
        material={materials.Wolf3D_Eye}
        skeleton={nodes.EyeRight.skeleton}
        morphTargetDictionary={nodes.EyeRight.morphTargetDictionary}
        morphTargetInfluences={nodes.EyeRight.morphTargetInfluences}
      />
      <skinnedMesh
        name="Wolf3D_Head"
        geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Head.geometry}
        material={materials.Wolf3D_Skin}
        skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Head.skeleton}
        morphTargetDictionary={nodes.Wolf3D_Head.morphTargetDictionary}
        morphTargetInfluences={nodes.Wolf3D_Head.morphTargetInfluences}
      />
      <skinnedMesh
        name="Wolf3D_Teeth"
        geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Teeth.geometry}
        material={materials.Wolf3D_Teeth}
        skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Teeth.skeleton}
        morphTargetDictionary={nodes.Wolf3D_Teeth.morphTargetDictionary}
        morphTargetInfluences={nodes.Wolf3D_Teeth.morphTargetInfluences}
      />
      <skinnedMesh
        geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Hair.geometry}
        material={materials.Wolf3D_Hair}
        skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Hair.skeleton}
      />
      <skinnedMesh
        geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Glasses.geometry}
        material={materials.Wolf3D_Glasses}
        skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Glasses.skeleton}
      />
      <skinnedMesh
        name="Wolf3D_Outfit_Top"
        geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top.geometry}
        material={materials.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top}
        skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top.skeleton}
        morphTargetDictionary={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top.morphTargetDictionary}
        morphTargetInfluences={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Top.morphTargetInfluences}
      />
      <skinnedMesh
        name="Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom"
        geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom.geometry}
        material={materials.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom}
        skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom.skeleton}
        morphTargetDictionary={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom.morphTargetDictionary}
        morphTargetInfluences={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Bottom.morphTargetInfluences}
      />
      <skinnedMesh
        name="Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear"
        geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear.geometry}
        material={materials.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear}
        skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear.skeleton}
        morphTargetDictionary={
          nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear.morphTargetDictionary
        }
        morphTargetInfluences={
          nodes.Wolf3D_Outfit_Footwear.morphTargetInfluences
        }
      />
      <skinnedMesh
        name="Wolf3D_Body"
        geometry={nodes.Wolf3D_Body.geometry}
        material={materials.Wolf3D_Body}
        skeleton={nodes.Wolf3D_Body.skeleton}
        morphTargetDictionary={nodes.Wolf3D_Body.morphTargetDictionary}
        morphTargetInfluences={nodes.Wolf3D_Body.morphTargetInfluences}
      />
    </group>
  );
}

useGLTF.preload("/images/3d/avatar.glb");
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Look at this: https://sbcode.net/react-three-fiber/animation-separate-file/ In my opinion you have mess between to separate files (names, parts, etc.).